# reactjs select with text filter

Tags: search, reactjs, autocomplete

I'm following the [thinking-in-react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) tutorial, and I know how to make the filter with displayed text, is there a way to change it so that the text is in a select / dropdown with a text filter?

I've been looking all over the net for a good tutorial but I can't seem to find one, I did find some modules but they are way too complex (I'm new to react).

Here is the javascript:

```
var ProductCategoryRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<tr><th colSpan="2">{this.props.category}</th></tr>);
  }
});

var ProductRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var name = this.props.product.stocked ?
      this.props.product.name :
      <span style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {this.props.product.name}
      </span>;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

var ProductTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
      if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
      }
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
      lastCategory = product.category;
    });
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          {' '}
          Only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var FilterableProductTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <ProductTable products={this.props.products} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: If I got it well, you want to add autocomplete to the Search Bar with a dropdown displaying the possible product names ?

Comment: Take a look at this component. http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

Comment: Thanks, this is the first one I looked at, I'm still trying to make sense of the code but it's a bit too complex for my understanding of react at this point, that's why I was looking for a tutorial on how to do it. (I'm looking to learn how it works not just use a module).

Comment: ok so while I'm looking at these / waiting to find a good tutorial, can someone tell me how / where to integrate this code into my node / react (eg, if I wanted to use this react-select in the above example, how would I do it)? I tried copying / pasting their code in different parts of the app but keep getting a blank screen when I run in (sorry i'm VERY new to react)